# Inject ViewModel and its property

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have ViewModel in my Silverlight project

```
public class MainViewModel : BaseNotify, IMainViewModel
{
    [Dependency("AccountID")]
    public Guid AccountID { get; set; }
    ...

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        if (AccountID != Guid.Empty)
        {
            PreSelectedAccount = new Account() { ID = AccountID };
            SingleAccountMode = true;
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

I'm using Unity this way:

```
public static class IoC
{
    static IoC()
    {
        Current = new UnityContainer();
        Current.RegisterType<IMainViewModel, MainViewModel>();
    }

    public static UnityContainer Current { get; set; }
}

public partial class App : Application
{
    [Dependency]
    public IMainViewModel ViewModel { get;  set; }

    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        Guid accountId = "1234-5678-1234-5678-1234";
        IoC.Current.BuildUp(this);
    }
}
```

After calling BuildUp method,I have instance of MainViewModel in the App.ViewModel, but how I can set up Unity to inject also some value for MainViewModel.AccountId property value during BuildUp?

Comment: Why would you inject a viewmodel ?? A ViewModel has no behavior, so I don't see any reason for injecting it. If you'd inject a viewmodelfactory, i'd understand but here it seems like an over use of dependency injection.

Comment: @remibourgarel  I made this for Unit-Testing purpose. And because the app will have some different business logic dependent on the user role. So I will create different implementation of IMainViewModel interface. A ViewModel definitely has behavior. It's not true that ViewModel doesn't have behavior

Comment: the viewmodel is the bridge between your model and the view, the logic is in the model, at best it's mapping logic, but do you really need to unit test a mapping logic ? And if it's because there'll be different implementation you are looking for a factory not a Service locator.

Answer (score 1):

You need to resolve/buildup with an [override](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660920%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx):

```
IoC.Current.BuildUp(this, new PropertyOverride("AccountID", accountId));
```

Comment: Thanks, its works. But I made this way:     `Current.RegisterType<IMainViewModel, MainViewModel>(new InjectionConstructor(accountId))
            .RegisterType<IProjectTreeViewModel, ProjectTreeViewModel>();`      And change constructor of MainViewModel to  pass GUID parameter

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like you are using the [ServiceLocator anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx). A pattern like [constructor injection](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) is most often preferable.

Another question: Why do you hook up your MainViewModel with your App class? Usually you would use it as the DataContext for your MainView.

And it is not common to inject primitive values like Guids using a DI container.

Comment: I did hook up in the App class because I fetching accountID variable in the App with non-trivial logic(I simplified code a bit). Actually after that I do bind ViewModel to DataContext:  `this.RootVisual = new MainPage {DataContext = ViewModel};`

Answer (score 0):

As @nemesv mention you might need to change your BuildUp method call, but doing so, I don't think you can achieve what you need.

The problem is first instance of the MainViewModel is created and then AccountId is passed into it, so your logic in the constructor is never true, e.g.

```
if(AccountID != Guid.Empty)
```

is never true. Alternativly you can add this logic to Setter of the AccountID property, something inline with this:

```
public Guid AccountId {
    get { return _accountId; }
    set {
        _accountId = value;
        OnAccountIdChanged();
    }
}

protected virtual void OnAccountIdChanged() {
    if(AccountId != Guid.Empty) {
       //do your thing here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I resolved issue with Instructor Injection. See my comment to @nemesv